# In BoilerplateJS browser is loading all the scripts (in other modules) regardless of the module activated

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, boilerplatejs

In the example project hosted at [BoilerplatJS](https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs) site, when we activate a particular sample module (for example clickCounter) all the scripts in other modules (component.js, viewmodel.js and others) gets loaded in the browser.

How to restrict this behavior in case we have to limit modules to users based on some kind of authorization?

Thanks!

Comment: There are some patterns for BilerplateJS lazy loading are discussed at the below link. I'm working on an implementation to support 'ConfigurableUI' + 'lazy-loading' currently and expect to release it soon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940262/pattern-for-lazy-loading-modules-on-demand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few things to note here.

- First regarding the files that load: In your production deployment, all these files will be combined, minified and obfuscated by the BoilerplateJS optimizer. Meaning, anyway all your code will be in a single script in production, this is normal in AMD JavaScript applications.
- Even though the code are loaded, the individual components will not be rendered until they receive an activation call from a front controller. Your module will register the UI components, at the initial application load time, but real creation of the UI component happens only in the 'activate' function of your component. This will ensure the application load time is faster and UI component creation happens only on demand.
- You should never depend on client side authorization in the application. All your JS code will go to the client browser and has potential to get modified. But for user friendliness, you may hide operation that are not permisible to the user. Where to do it depends on the granularity of control. If you want it at component level, you may do this on the navigation menu itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Answered my question comprehensively!

Comment: Incase you want to divide your application in to multiple singlepage subsystems, here is a good read: http://blog.hasith.net/2012/11/how-much-multi-page-single-page.html

Comment: Also see the relavant question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676333/lazy-loading-boilerplate-modules